# Extracting delimited data from .txt file into vector

Tags: python, excel, extract, delimiter

I've been looking around for a solution to this with minimal luck and I would appreciate any advice or help.

I'm working in Python 3 in Jupyter Notebooks.

Say I have a words.txt file with information like the following:

```
(50)  PMC3933789  (view)
(36)  PMC4763238  (view)
(35)  PMC2821926  (view)
(26)  PMC3154047  (view)
(25)  PMC3471816  (view)
(25)  PMC4350884  (view)
(24)  PMC2809798  (view)
(23)  PMC2861733  (view)
(22)  PMC4556980  (view)
(22)  PMC4811477  (view)
(19)  PMC3271181  (view)
(19)  PMC3549280  (view)
(19)  PMC4879671  (view)
(18)  PMC2938390  (view)
(18)  PMC3186417  (view)
(18)  PMC3498278  (view)
(18)  PMC3601842  (view)
(16)  PMC3445503  (view)
(16)  PMC3491835  (view)
```

In Python, I want to read this .txt file, extract the delimited numbers, and assign them to a vector i.e.:

```
var = [3933789, 4763238, 2821926...]
```

Previously, I've been using Excel and manually delimiting the numbers, appending a comma, and then manually copying the resulting values, but this is tedious when the number of arguments increases. I'd like to be able to do this in Python.

Comment: I think this should cover your use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25758542/14518942

Comment: There are plenty of examples of reading a text file line by line. Then use split() on the line, and extract from the 3rd character.

Comment: One approach us regular expression in a list comprehension: `import re; with open('mydata.txt', 'r') as file:
    var = [int(re.search('PMC(\d+)', line).group(1)) for line in file]`, where mydata.txt is your text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach us regular expression in a list comprehension

```
import re
with open('mydata.txt', 'r') as file:  # mydata.txt is name of data file    
    var = [int(re.search(r'PMC(\d+)', line).group(1)) for line in file]
```

Explanation

```
r'PMC(\d+)'                    - regular expression for capturing digits after PMC
re.search(r'PMC(\d+)', line)   - finds and captures digits in a line
re.search(...).group(1)         - correspond to capture group 1 which are the digits
int(...)                       - converts digits from string to number
for line in file               - iterates through the lines of the file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to strip by fixed indices if this is a consistent pattern:

```
with open('my-file','r') as lines:
    numbers = [int(line[9:16]) for line in lines.readlines() if len(line.strip()) > 0]
print(numbers)
```

which for the above example, gives:

```
[3933789, 4763238, 2821926, 3154047, 3471816, 4350884, 2809798, 2861733, 4556980, 4811477, 3271181, 3549280, 4879671, 2938390, 3186417, 3498278, 3601842, 3445503, 3491835]
```